# try to kill all nodes but failed on osx

Tags: macos, node.js

I hope to restart nodejs on mac osx

```
$ps aux | grep node
mymac      20215   0.0  0.0  2432768    460 s000  R+    9:49AM   0:00.00 grep node
```

there is one PID 20215, I try to kill the process

```
kill -2 20215
```

it reports

```
-bash: kill: (20215) - No such process
```

your comment welcome

Answer (score 122, accepted):

There's no other process containing the keyword "node" in your `ps aux` output except from `grep node`. You're trying to kill the process of `grep`ing node, and no node process is running, that's why it fails.

Try with

```
sudo killall node
```

Or

```
sudo kill -9 `ps aux | grep node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: sudo killall node reports:No matching processes were found

Comment: sudo kill -9 `ps aux | grep node | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'` reports kill: 20397: No such process

Comment: Just run `node whatever.js`, there's no `node` processes running. It will obviously report "No such process", the grep process that appears just ended with grep.

Comment: I still see node process with this command: `ps -ef | grep node`

Comment: hi, here what does -9 mean?

Comment: how do I kill "single" node instead of "all"??

Comment: `killall node` worked for me like a charm. I did not have to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
killall -s KILL node
```

Comment: ``` killall -s KILL node ```

Answer (score 1):

Below command should work

```
killall node
```

Reference for more commands

[ps commands](https://ss64.com/osx/killall.html)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow none of the answers worked for me as I get an error like "no such process".
The error I was getting is `listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use`.
What worked for me was (assuming port 3000 was used):

```
lsof -i :3000
sudo kill <RESULTING_PID>
```