# nodejs runs every time when osx startup

Tags: node.js, osx-mountain-lion

I call command
ps aux | grep node

it displays

```
 mymac       565   0.1  0.0  2423356    184 s000  R+   12:39PM   0:00.00 grep node
```

I checked system preferences login item, there is  pre-startup item for node.

how to avoid its node starting up or kill its process?

I try to use sudo killall node, but no result

your comment welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [try to kill all nodes but failed on osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968069/try-to-kill-all-nodes-but-failed-on-osx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is showing the `grep` process.  Node isn't running.